# No value given for one or more required parameters when updating MS-Access table

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I'm trying to update a table in Access, and I've been trying to do this for some time, but I keep getting the same error.

This is the code:

```
try
{
    selectedID = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text;
            
    string constr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + databasePath;
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);

    con.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE TABLE1 SET [Désignation du matériel] = @DesMateriel, [Unité] = @unite, [Opérations] = @operation, [Produits] = @produit, [Matricule] = @matricule,[Message arrivé du DCM] = @messageArrivé,[Sous - Direction] = @sousDirection,[N°PV Unité] = @PVUnite,[Période] = @Periode,[N°CR du CIDME] = @cidme,[Remarque] = @remarque where ID = @ID"); 
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", selectedID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DesMateriel", comboBox4.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unite", textBox5.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operation", textBox12.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@produit", comboBox3.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matricule", Convert.ToInt64(textBox13.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@messageArrivé", textBox15.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sousDirection", textBox17.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PVUnite", textBox19.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Periode", textBox18.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cidme", textBox16.Text.ToString());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarque", textBox14.Text.ToString());

    int returnedValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MessageBox.Show("Enregistrement à jour");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Erreur, veuillez contactez le développeur" + ex.ToString());
}
```

I've found many people facing the same error message (not the same scenario) but none of the answers helped.

I copied the query to access and tried to run it, just to see if I'm missing something in the syntax and it's fine.

I also printed all the textboxes and combo boxes in the console to see if any of them is null, but that was not the case either.

Comment: `@ID` is in the wrong position (in the sequence of parameters you're adding). -- Why do you have all those, e.g.,  `textBox5.Text.ToString()`? The `Text` property already returns a string, what is `.ToString()` for? -- `AddWithValue()` is not a great idea here. -- Connection and Command are Disposable objects, usually declared with `using`  statements (which also takes care of closing the Connection). -- As already mentioned, you should use a DataGridView, not a ListView.

Comment: @Jimi Does the order matter?

Comment: Yes, OleDb parameters are positional. The *name* you assign to a parameter is not even taken into consideration (it doesn't *see* it).

Comment: @Jimi Thanks. I appreciate it. The code is still returning the same error though.

Comment: I cannot see what you're passing to the query. Or what Type are those parameters. `ID` is probably an auto-increment Column. Try to pass values that match the Columns' Type (which implies using [Paramters.Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.add) and validate the inputs) -- You need to debug your code, see what values come in when you build that query. -- Do yourself a favor, assign meaningful names to your Controls. -- It appears you haven't read much of the docs I linked before.

Comment: Can you try adding `+ ""` to all of your string parameters? for instance: `textBox5.Text.ToString() + ""`. Maybe oledb is interpreting empty string parameters as null?

Comment: @Crowcoder Thanks for your response. I have tried that, and it's still returning the same error.